# Using slick slider filter on the navigation as well as the main gallery

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am trying to use slick slides filter option and having some trouble getting it to work on both the navigation slides and the main slide as well.

Here is a fiddle example with what I have already:
https://jsfiddle.net/haggotx5/

After I filter out the white slides by selecting white from the dropdown and then click on the last slide of the 4 showing, it is now out of sync.. So now #5 opens #6 slide above. Am I using the filter incorrectly?

```
<div class="slider-for">
  <div class="item red">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    6
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider-nav">
  <div class="item red">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="item white">
    6
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<select id='color'>
  <option value="">Filter</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    focusOnSelect: true
  });
  $("#color").change(function(){
    color = $(this).val();
    $('.slider-nav').slick("slickUnfilter");
    $('.slider-for').slick("slickUnfilter");
    $('.slider-nav').slick("slickFilter",'.'+color);
    $('.slider-for').slick("slickFilter",'.'+color);
  })
})
```

Comment: Not understand your question what you want?

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1043

Comment: I am also facing this Issue today.